# Getting "wrong" certificate when browsing to websites

Tags: windows, browser, certificate

Scenario:

- User browses to a site that he didn't visit recently (hours), e.g. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
- User gets error message from browser that the certificate is invalid.

Observation:

- The certificate shown by the browser is always for [www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com).
- No apple devices are available (none of the two routers, none of the clients)
- After some time (varies from seconds to minutes) everything works fine again.
- Previously McAfee was installed, today, the machines carry ESet. Didn't change the issue.
- The problem is very intermittent (every few days) and is usually gone before we get to debug.

Context:

- Windows 10
- Several browsers (Chrome, Edge)
- Several machines
- Single WLAN network (issue does not occur on others)

Question:

- Any suggestions on what/how to debug?

Error message (in Dutch):

[image: Error message in Dutch language]

Comment: Can you show the certificate chain (the 3rd tab)? Does the _root_ certificate look legit, and not something made up on-the-spot by ESET Antivirus?

Comment: (1) Does clearing browser data & cache help? (2) Does it happen when all browser extensions are disabled? (3) Do you use proxies? (4) You could temporarily try to disable security software.